# How to extract the study area from a netCDF by a shapefile boundary with Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, netcdf, extract

I have a global size netCDF document, the variable is three dimensions, including time. lat and lon. I have a shapefile boundary for my study area, both of them have same projection. How can I extract the study area from the netCDF by the shapefile boundary?

Comment: The netCDF data foramt is a raster data source and you could follow the basic instructions from the codebook (masking, select boundaries etc.) Look at https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python)