# Extract temperature data from NC file using GeoPandas polygon in Python 3

Tags: python, netcdf, extract-by-mask

I am trying to draw a polygon in the NC file and extract temperature value from this polygon using Python.

```
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping
geodf = geopandas.read_file('myfile.shp')
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio('myfile.nc')
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Why are you bothering with python? Just do it using the tools in your GIS system, which by the way you do not mention. ArcMap has a suite of tools for extracting data out of net cdf format into a GIS format then you can ask your spatial question.

Comment: I have about 300 NC files. I want to use a loop in python. I can do it by manually .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rioxarray`:

- [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python/354798#354798)
- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```