# CRS Error when clipping NetCDF using a shapefile

Tags: netcdf, xarray, rioxarray

When trying to mask a NetCDF (a daily time series of 31 days) with the code below, I get the following error related to the part of writing the CRS to the rio NetCDF data:

```
CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 6
```

Here is the code I am using (taken from snowman2's answer here: [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python)):

```
import rioxarray
import xarray
from shapely.geometry import mapping

ERA5_daily = xarray.open_dataarray('ERA5_VIMD_2018_08_Daily.nc')
ERA5_daily.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="longitude", y_dim="latitude", inplace=True)
ERA5_daily.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
shapefile = geopandas.read_file('Cluster_34586.shp', crs="epsg:4326")

clipped = ERA5_daily.rio.clip(shapefile.geometry.apply(mapping), shapefile.crs, drop=False)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import rioxarray; rioxarray.show_versions()"`? What is the CRS?

Comment: Hi, @snowman2! This is what I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-54d7e150b1f6>", line 1, in <module>
    rioxarray.show_versions()

AttributeError: module 'rioxarray' has no attribute 'show_versions'`

Comment: @snowman2: 
It looks like there is no CRS (couldn't find it either when opening the netcdf file in python with netcdf library, rioxarray or when opening with QGIS)

Comment: I think that you have an old version of rioxarray. Mind updating and trying again?

Comment: Are you able to share the file? Or the output of `ncdump -h file.nc`?

Comment: Yes, I can share it. But I don't know how to do it here. Is it possible to share the file through StackExchange?

Comment: Usually people upload it to dropbox, google drive, etc. and then put the link here.

Comment: Thank you! I uploaded the .nc file and the shape file. Here it is: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkyHT1Zp7qCSuf4uZSTBBQJ2zu94Cg?e=OwLUJc

Answer (score 1):

Using this code:

```py
import geopandas
import rioxarray
import xarray
from shapely.geometry import mapping

ERA5_daily = xarray.open_dataarray('ERA5_VIMD_2018_08.nc')
ERA5_daily.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
shapefile = geopandas.read_file('Cluster_34586.shp', crs="EPSG:4326")
clipped = ERA5_daily.rio.clip(shapefile.geometry.apply(mapping), shapefile.crs, drop=False)
```

It works with this setup (from: `rioxarray.show_versions()`):

```
rioxarray (0.0.31) deps:
  rasterio: 1.1.5
    xarray: 0.16.0
      GDAL: 3.0.4

Other python deps:
     scipy: 1.5.2
    pyproj: 2.6.1.post1

System:
    python: 3.7.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 31 2020, 02:25:08)  [GCC 7.5.0]
```

I would recommend upgrading the versions you have on your system.

Comment: I've uninstalled rioxarray and installed again using pip install and it is now with the same version as yours. The code is now working just fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked 