# Issue in calculating NDVI using Rasterio Python

Tags: python, rasterio, numpy, rioxarray

I am trying to calculate NDVI using two clipped raster images of Landsat 7 (NIR & Red Bands clipped using mask file) using the following code:

```
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with rio.open(r'D:\clip_test_b3.tif') as src:
    red = src.read(1)   # (Rows, Columns) = (2731, 3660)
    
with rio.open(r'D:\clip_test_b4.tif') as src:
    nir = src.read(1)   # (Rows, Columns) = (2730, 3635)
    
np.seterr(divide = 'ignore', invalid = 'ignore')

ndvi = (nir.astype(float) - red.astype(float))/(nir + red)

plt.imshow(ndvi)
```

In the above code both the bands (Red & NIR) are of different shapes (different rows and columns).
After running the above code I am getting message "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2730,3635) (2731,3660) ".

But when same NDVI calculation I am trying to do in ArcMap (using Raster Calculator), then NDVI is getting calculated.

Can someone please help me out in solving out this error.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/374507/edit) to include your `clip` code, you're getting different sized outputs. And also `rio info` or `gdalinfo` outputs for the pre-clip dataset/s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, you need to ensure the grids cover the same area and have the same dimensions. One method to achieve this is with the [reproject_match](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html) method in `rioxarray` (geospatial xarray extension powered by rasterio).

```py
import rioxarray

red = rioxarray.open_rasterio("D:\clip_test_b3.tif")
nir_original = rioxarray.open_rasterio("D:\clip_test_b4.tif")

nir = nir_original.rio.reproject_match(red)
ndvi = (nir.astype(float) - red.astype(float))/(nir + red)

ndvi.plot()
```

Comment: +1 this answers the question and addresses the symptoms (and I wasn't aware of this useful functionality, so thanks), but I think if something has gone awry in the OPs clipping that they probably need to sort it out instead of just dealing with the different shapes afterwards.

Comment: True. You can use `rioxarray` to clip if you want to start from the beginning: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354798/144357 or https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

Comment: Thanks, I must have a look at rioxarray sometime.

Comment: @snowman2. Thank for your help. It has solved my issue. I think there wasn't any issue with clipping. As the bands (Red & NIR) corresponds to the same "Path & Row" of Landsat-7, after making the polygon of the valid data for both the bands I found that both the polygons doesn't overlap exactly over each other. Because of this when I am masking the bands by using my study area the shapes of both the bands are not exactly same. Small edit in your solution "nir = nir_original.reproject_match(red)" should be changed to "nir = nir_original.rio.reproject_match(red)"

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked - and good catch with the missing rio. I just updated the answer.