# Clip nc file with shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, netcdf

I know the question has been asked before, but I get an error trying to clip my nc file with a shapefile with the method used in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354798).

My error is `DimensionError: x dimension not found. 'set_spatial_dims()' can address this.`

My code is

```
path = 'a/given/path/'
import geopandas
import rioxarray
import xarray
from shapely.geometry import mapping


nc = xarray.open_dataarray(path + 'FR.nc')
nc.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
nc.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
shp = geopandas.read_file('AK.shp', crs="epsg:4326")

clipped = chen.rio.clip(AK_Shape.geometry.apply(mapping), AK_Shape.crs, drop=False)
```

The nc file and the shape file has the following dimension and information

```
nc: <xarray.DataArray 'FR' (lat: 180, lon: 360, model: 15, regr: 5)>
shp: Index(['AREA', 'PERIMETER', 'STATESP010', 'STATE', 'STATE_FIPS', 'ORDER_ADM',
       'MONTH_ADM', 'DAY_ADM', 'YEAR_ADM', 'geometry'],
      dtype='object')
```

Can I do a work around and then get the cut-out version of my nc file with the shapefile?

Comment: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/47

Comment: @Erik, I still do not understand the problem. It asks me to use the 'set_spatial_dims()', and I do. But then I still get that problem. Your link did not solve my problem sorry.