# Masking satellite data using shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, landsat, masking, rioxarray

I am using Landsat data to determine NDVI for a specific region of interest (roi). However, the roi has buildings and other artificial objects that I wish to mask.

I have followed through the example at [Masking NetCDF time series data from shapefile using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python).

However, this method masks all data outside of the shapefile, and retains the data from inside of the shapefile.

Has anybody any solutions for doing the reverse of this, and thus masking the data INSIDE the shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

You just need to pass in `invert=True`:

```py
clipped = xds.rio.clip(......, invert=True)
```

Comment: Cheers @snowman2. Such a simple solution, and worked as expected.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked 